# Left join tables (1:n) using Pandas, keeping number of rows the same as left table

Tags: python, pandas, join, group-by, left-join

How do I left join tables with 1:n relationship, while keeping the number of rows the same as left table and concatenating any duplicate data with a character/string like ';'.

**Example:**  
 Country Table

```
CountryID      Country      Area
1              UK           1029
2              Russia       8374
```

Cities Table

```
CountryID      City     
1              London           
1              Manchester       
2              Moscow          
2              Ufa
```

I want:

```
CountryID      Country      Area      Cities
1              UK           1029      London;Manchester
2              Russia       8374      Moscow;Ufa
```

I know how to perform a normal left join

```
country.merge(city, how='left', on='CountryID')
```

which gives me four rows instead of two:

```
Area      Country      CountryID      City
1029      UK           1              London
1029      UK           1              Manchester
8374      Russia       2              Moscow
8374      Russia       2              Ufa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by `groupby` + `join` for new column in `df1` if performance is important:

```
df1['Cities'] = df1['CountryID'].map(df2.groupby('CountryID')['City'].apply(';'.join))
print (df1)
   CountryID Country  Area             Cities
0          1      UK  1029  London;Manchester
1          2  Russia  8374         Moscow;Ufa
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2.groupby('CountryID')['City'].apply(';'.join))
CountryID
1    London;Manchester
2           Moscow;Ufa
Name: City, dtype: object
```

Another solution with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df1.join(df2.groupby('CountryID')['City'].apply(';'.join), on='CountryID')
print (df)
   CountryID Country  Area               City
0          1      UK  1029  London;Manchester
1          2  Russia  8374         Moscow;Ufa
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the desired result:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='CountryID').groupby(['CountryID', 'Country', 'Area']).agg({'City': lambda x: ';'.join(x)}).reset_index()

#   CountryID Country  Area               City
#0          1      UK  1029  London;Manchester
#1          2  Russia  8374         Moscow;Ufa
```